# Глупые вопросы в плюсе. Накрутка репутации?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Возможно, что уже обсуждалось, но поиском я не нашёл. Возможно, что и обсуджения не стоит. Каждый из нас множество раз натыкался на вопросы предельно простые, ответ на которые есть в документации, на вопросы, проблема которых вызвана обычной опечаткой, и даже на откровенно глупые. Тысячи их. Но некоторые из них почему-то имеют положительный рейтинг. Кто их плюсует и почему?

Пара примеров:

1. [В чем отличие getExternalFilesDir от getExternalStorageDir?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610538/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-getexternalfilesdir-%D0%BE%D1%82-getexternalstoragedir)
2. [Создание объекта в другом классе Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574036/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-python/574039)

Comment: По одному плюсу в каждом из вопросов. Это ли накрутка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @alexolut дело не в большом количестве "плохих" вопросов, дело в том, что кто-то их плюсует непонятно за что. Так что это не дубль.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, плюсы как и минусы - дело сугубо личных предпочтений. Плюсануть могут не только за хороший вопрос, но и за оформление, за манеры, за помощь с другим вопросом, по ходу фарма значка, по ходу ревью из очереди и тд. Например во втором случае я предполагаю что было как-то так: зашел человек, пристально поглядел в код, ошибки не увидел. Решил "что-то я не понимаю, отлаживать лень", и плюсанул.

Comment: Может и не накрутка. Но если плюс первому вопросу я ещё могу объяснить другим пользователем, который тоже не нашёл в себе сил прочитать документацию, то логику плюса второму никак.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, смотрите, мог плюсануть человек не знавший реешния (ну если знал бы, он бы его написал, так?)), и предположивший что тут может быть незнакомая тонкость. Или человек из очереди проверок первых сообщений, увидевший вопрос по вообще незнакомой теме, но нормально оформленный.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму у меня это не укладывается в голове, я бы так не сделал, но это вполне может быть объяснением. Спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я по своему языку плюсую вопросы в которых какое-то необъяснимое мне поведение и в чем дело - я с ходу не понимаю, а отлаживать - нет времени. Иногда это бывает что-то глупое в результате. Но если я с ходу не вижу ответ, то считаю что наверное вопрос задан не зря)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, ну и ошибки типа "тупо не тот символ", не всегда на совести автора кода например: https://github.com/reinderien/mimic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В целом, простые базовые вопросы всегда будут получать больше голосов, чем сложные, понятные только экспертам. Аналогично, ответы по популярным технологиям вроде [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) будут получать больше голосов, чем ответы по [perl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) или [fortran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran). Больше аудитория — больше просмотров, больше голосов. Стоит ли об этом беспокоиться?

Первый вопрос — хороший, хоть и простой. В ответах на него можно рассказать что-нибудь фундаментальное и важное. Например, во [втором ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/610562/181472) автор довольно подробно рассказывает про типы хранилищ и применение каждого из методов.

Второй вопрос вызван опечаткой в коде. Маловероятно, что кто-то наткнётся на такую же опечатку в таком же коде, поэтому такие вопросы мы закрываем. Неожиданно, что ответ получил целых четыре плюса — возможно, за наблюдательность.

Почему вопросы получили по одному плюсу? Так бывает, множество вариантов предложены в комментариях. Из того, что не предложено: отредактировал чужой вопрос, посмотрел как всё стало красиво, плюсанул. Всё это — не накрутка репутации. Накрутку, т.е. систематическое голосование за вопросы и ответы конкретного участника, часто с использованием фиктивных учётных записей, модераторы регулярно обнаруживают и откатывают.

Comment: А [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716686/204271) за что можно было плюсануть?

Comment: Или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719043/204271).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev shit happens. Бывает, что кто-нибудь голосует невпопад. Воспринимайте это как помехи, белый шум. Общую статистику он не испортит. Кстати, первый вопрос, на мой взгляд, довольно интересный. По крайней мере он показывает, что автор хочет разобраться в сути.