# Насколько мы с вами 'be nice'?

Tags: обсуждение, новые-участники

Открытый вопрос ко всем, кто хочет рассказать, как он себе видит наше сообщество, его постоянных членов -- тех, кто регулярно заходит пару раз в неделю на сайт, отвечает на вопросы или задаёт свои.

"Какие мы и насколько мы соответствуем принципу [be nice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)?"

Вопрос написан по мотивам реальных событий, не хотел бы упоминать в связи с конкретным последним случаем, потому что их только на последней неделе два или три было. Давайте поговорим в общем, без перехода на конкретные личности.

Мы себя представляем (хотим представлять) как сообщество профессионалов, которое ориентировано на знание, которое помогает новичкам и так далее и тому подобное. Очень хороший пример того, как это выглядит со стороны описан на примере [Somehow Someway Ltd](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339104/): где-то благодушно поинтересовались, где-то хитро улыбнулись, где-то уточнили -- но в целом либо прямо даём ответ на вопрос, либо где-то помогаем в нужную сторону подтолкнуть.

А на деле? Не выглядит ли это со стороны как "я зашёл, создал НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ вопрос, а мне в комментариях начали язвить, плюнул -- ушёл с сайта"?

Замечали ли вы такие случаи, много ли их по-вашему? Точнее так: это бывает достаточно редко и можно считать, что мы достаточно 'be nice' или это бывает достаточно часто и это прям "ужас-ужас"? Или же можно говорить, что как в Греции демократия не распространялась на рабов, так и необязательно быть найс для тех, кто приходит и создаёт совершенно нетематичные вопросы про биологию на казахском, домашку по информатике и т.п.?

И отдельная группа вопросов: что с этим делать? По порядку: плох ли сложившийся порядок (может хорош и менять ничего не надо?), если плох, то нужно ли что-то менять? Если менять, то как (допустим, ставить тревоги на подобные комментарии чтобы потом их вырезали).

Comment: иногда мы слишком be nice :)

Comment: много букв, надо tl;dr

Comment: ну вот... опять я что-то интересное пропустил :(

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice я более чем уверен, что некоторые это в первый раз увидят.

Comment: Ого! 3 супер-закрывателя. Закрывать на Мете тему, которая  совершенно однозначно (да, тавтология) по теме! Хотелось бы знать этих героев (на месте модератора я бы забанил их без объяснения причин (и занес IP в черный список))

Comment: @avp ну банить по IP это перебор ;) они же не виноваты, что движок дает такие большие возможности для злоупотреблений

Comment: @VadimTagil, это для острастки остальных. Мало ли, какие возможности есть, головой всегда надо думать

Comment: @avp банить не буду, но если вопрос закроют — переоткрою, конечно же.

Answer (score 10):

Русский Stackoverflow - это самый дружелюбный ресурс, который я вообще встречал в РуНете за 20 лет! А лично я злобный и раздражительный, за что постоянно испытываю вину. Не в последнюю очередь я на SO для того, чтобы научиться быть терпимее.

С другой стороны, не только на SO, но и на других ресурсах, а также среди соискателей на рабочие места я всё больше вижу людей, которые разбираться не хотят, а хотят только готовых ответов. Они даже не пытаются правильно сформулировать вопрос. Не говоря уж о чтении правил. Если такие люди и их вопросы не будут отфильтровываться, они забьют ресурс шумом, сделают его менее полезным и удобным для людей, которые действительно стараются ответы искать.

Всё хорошо в меру. Надо стараться быть терпимее, но не стоит лояльничать с наглыми и ленивыми.

P.S. Надо признать, что умение и желание самостоятельно искать ответы, а также правильно задавать вопросы во мне развила именно жёсткая критика со стороны старших коллег. Иногда пинок бывает очень полезен.

Comment: Кандидаты в модераторы могут почерпать отсюда идей на предлагаемые им вопросы :)

Comment: Модератора ответ. ) Вы, часом, не хотите выдвинуться? Вангую: ответ нещадно заплюсуют... Но... По сути имху сказано мало, аккуратно обошли все острые углы.

Comment: @AK не считаю себя достойным. Может быть когда-нибудь...

Comment: @AK касательно же конкретики: _Замечали ли вы такие случаи, много ли их по-вашему?_ Не мало. Но в львиной доле случаев это обоснованная агрессивная реакция. _Что с этим делать?_ Пока ничего. В данный момент правила адекватны, модерация эффективна, саморегуляция сообщества работает. Проблемы я не вижу. Есть недовольство небольшой группы. Но, во-первых, всем нравиться невозможно, недовольство будет всегда, а во-вторых, основная масса недовольным - это люди того типа, которые всегда всем недовольны и у которых всегда виноват кто-то, но не они сами. На сколько я могу судить.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev агрессивная реакция не бывает обоснованной. На сайте есть инструменты для сдерживания халявщиков, ленивых и тех, кто не хочет нормально формулировать вопросы. Минусы на вопросах бесплатны. Минусы очень быстро убирают вопрос с главной и приводят к question ban. Т.е. механизмы фильтрации есть, и они достаточно эффективны и без нарушения be nice. Нет никакого смысла тратить свое время и выливать очередное "погугли ж ты!" на человека, который даже не попытался сформулировать вопрос. В вас критика развила умение задавать вопросы.

Comment: @PashaPash в целом согласен, но упомяну одну проблему, по поводу которой я уже создавал на Мете [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4418/204271): многие вопросы без видимого повода сразу же получают плюс, а иногда и не один. Это, во-первых, навешивает психологический щит от большей части пользователей и, во-вторых, приводит к тому, что нужно больше пользователей, чтобы вопрос отфильтровать. Иногда это заканчивается появлением пользователей типа [Flippy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194625/flippy). Так что эффективность механизмов саморегуляции не стопроцентная.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Плюсы всегда субъективны. Например, я не понимаю, откуда столько плюсов на [вот этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505018/). Ответ не него есть прямо в документации по ключевому слово yield :(. Чем плох Flippy? Ну да, он когда-то постил трешовые вопросы. Перевоспитался, начал постить более-менее ответы. Те, кто не хотел читать его вопросы - проходили мимо. Действительно проблемные пользователи - это [komra23](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-info/216027). он же tode,он же sharper, он же еще штук 20 клонов, созданных для обхода question ban.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev кстати, Flippy даже банили "за низкое качество участия". Сомневаюсь, что нарушение be-nice и проявление агрессии как-то помогло бы ему сосредоточится и начать постить нормальные вопросы.

Comment: @PashaPash да я не против принципа be-nice, я наоборот обеими руками за!

Answer (score 5):

**Добавлено**:

Всё же, посмотрев повнимательнее, понял, что всё намного сложнее, чем показалось вначале. "Мусорных" вопросов достаточно много, в частности, из-за них, возможно, не получают внимания действительно полезные вопросы. И тут получается палка о двух концах - либо вырезать лишнее (и тогда, возможно, приток новичков немного меньше будет, чем мог бы), либо оставлять лишнее (и тогда, опять же, те, чьи вопросы не получили внимания из-за того что до них не дошли - тоже, возможно, уйдут).
Добавлю также, что через пару дней просмотра однообразных скучных вопросов (когда люди даже однострочное описание функции из мануала не могут прочитать), всё это начало немного раздражать.

**Первоначально**:

Да, таких случаев много. Даже слишком много.

С самого начала изучения php я большую часть ответов на свои вопросы находил на stackoverflow. Но не здесь, не в русскоязычном сообществе, а в англоязычном. И я не мог понять - как так? Русских же не так мало, в действительности, нас очень-очень много и это реально странно, почему здесь так отстают от английских товарищей. php.net весь перевели, я крайне редко натыкаюсь на страницы, где нет русского перевода (чаще всего это абсолютно бесполезные функции или устаревшие расширения). А тут - может вопросы никто не задаёт? (думал я)

Три дня назад, заскучав, решил: "А может попробовать начать делиться своим опытом? Не на пенсии же этим заниматься, когда в маразм впаду". За три дня я просмотрел около 100 вопросов и ужаснулся увиденному. В 90% случаев сюжет такой: есть у человека задача, которую ему нужно решить - но он не понимает как. Заходит он на SO, описывает всё. А дальше начинается самое ужасное и отвратительное - его всеми возможными способами поливают г...рязью. Написал свои жалкие попытки неправильно выполнить задачу? Получи еще больше грязи. Использует устаревшее расширение mysql вместо mysqli/PDO? Значит тебе напишут еще как минимум 4 комментария "зачем вы используете устаревшее mysql?" в различной формулировке.

Ну нет у вас времени отвечать на все вопросы, не достоин этот слишком простой вопрос вашего внимания - ну так пройдите мимо. Для чего убивать у людей желание в принципе задавать вопросы?

Может Вы ошибаетесь, и это не "сообщество профессионалов, которое ориентировано на знание", а "платформа для самоутверждения и издевательств над нубами"? Издевательства умного над глупым, как и издевательство знающего над незнающим - эти вещи ничем не отличаются от издевательств сильного над слабым. Но только последнее людям кажется "чем-то ужасным".

Comment: Одно дело - когда вопрос действительно непонятный или неполный. Другое дело - когда человек задаёт корректный вопрос, но люди считают его слишком лёгким и очевидным и "вообще это везде написано". Может быть оно и вылазит у Вас первой строчкой в гугле, но Вы не думали, что это еще и из-за того, что Вы знаете что искать? Вы знаете ответ и уже формулируете вопрос так, чтобы поисковая система выдала Вам именно то, что нужно. Но ведь большая часть задающих вопросы не знают что искать.

Comment: Психологи говорят, что всегда есть разница между тем, как человек воспринимает себя, каким он себя видит, и тем, какой-он-есть-на-самом-деле, мы многое вытесняем из сознания. То, что у нас есть идеалы ("общество ИТ-знаний", "be nice") не означает, что все мы и всегда соответствуем этим идеалам. Думать, что все и всегда пытаются вникнуть в вопрос -- очень большая ошибка, собственно именно за "даже не хочет разобраться" больше всего получают минусов.

Comment: И вот какая штука... Этот метод кнута очень хорошо формирует сообщество тех, кто хочет/старается разобраться, и с точки зрения "эффективного менеджера"™ [сообщества], но является ли этот метод be nice и не слишком ли много людей уходит "в расход" и "в утиль"?

Comment: Вы не могли бы добавить конкретики в свой ответ? Ссылки на примеры подобных вопросов. Для уточнения, насколько можно судить речь идет только (или преимущественно) о вопросах с меткой `php`?

Comment: Давайте определимся, что это две совершенно разные проблемы. Первая - неуважение новичков. Люди скидывают гигантскую кучу безобразия с вопросом "почему у меня не работает?". Или не задают вопросы. Или... Вы сами можете прочитать список причин для удаления вопросов. И с этим всё нормально - человек задал вопрос, его вопрос через некоторое время удаляют. Но вторая проблема не имеет на данный момент решения, о ней и пишет автор данной темы. Старички не хотят "be nice".

Comment: Извините, но "нет", конкретики я не добавлю. Это не принесёт никакой пользы в обсуждение. Более того, автор вопроса попросил "без перехода на конкретные личности", а приведение конкретных примеров этим и будет являться. Зайдите в вопросы и помониторьте новые. Вы сами всё увидите.

Comment: И я еще раз очень прошу - разделите эти две проблемы. То, на что Вы все указываете - "неуважение новичков" - не относится к теме. И с этим проблем нет - такие вопросы быстро "чистятся". Здесь обсуждается то, что "слишком много лишнего попадает под зачистку".

Comment: @АлександрБелинский пожалуйста используйте пинги при обращении к конкретному участнику или хотя бы цитаты - не всегда понятно к кому именно адресовано ваше сообщение.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский "И я еще раз очень прошу - разделите эти две проблемы. То, на что Вы все указываете - "неуважение новичков" - не относится к теме." вы ошибаетесь, в моем комментарии нет ничего, что указывает на так называемое "неуважение новичков"

Comment: Извиняюсь, это не Вам, @FoggyFinder, было адресовано - это было к комментариям другого ответившего, но его ответ был удалён.

Comment: нет проблем, в целом я с вами согласен, но не во всем, нужно будет еще свой ответ написать не забыть

Comment: `Старички не хотят "be nice"` -- вы видите именно тех, кто не следует принципу "не нравится вопрос, пройди мимо" (а другим, наверное,  просто не хочется "лезть в драку" с этими активистами (тем более, что их позиция похоже близка к позиции администрации SO))

Comment: @FoggyFinder если успеете )) Вопрос похоже, скоро закроют. И мне прямо любопытно посмотреть, чьи это голоса.

Comment: @AK если скоро закроют, то не успею. Хм, чем же вопрос то не угодил

Comment: Предположу что вы хотели написать не в русском, а в русскоязычном. Давайте все-таки разделять.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Пожалуйста, приведите ссылки, где происходит описанное вами в ответе (я постараюсь сделать все возможно, чтобы подобного не происходило).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, что-то и правда за последние два дня примеров не нашел. Видать вначале просто показалось, либо я в неудачное время тогда попал.

Comment: _"Мусорных" вопросов достаточно много, в частности, из-за них, возможно, не получают внимания действительно полезные вопросы_ - Это не совсем так. Скорее похоже на описание проблемы форумов. На SO из-за хорошей системы поиска и категоризации нет проблемы отделения интересных вопросов от шлака. SO больше угрожает проблема потери интересных "пограничных" вопросов из-за легкости закрывашек и слишком жесткого автоудаления духом

Comment: _"последние два дня примеров не нашел"_ - неудивительно, что не нашли: проблемные вопросы без заплюсованных ответов труться либо автоматически духом, либо самим автором под давлением минусов...

Comment: на enSO хялявщиков, ленивых и прочих help vampires гораздо больше. дело в том, что на enSO вы приходите из поисковиков, в хорошие заплюсованные вопросы и ответы. на ruSO вы пытаетесь отвечать на все подряд. попробуйте поотвечать на все подряд на enSO, для сравнения )

Answer (score 4):

Нет, не `be-nice`.

Срок моего пребывания в сообществе еще даже не составил год, но уже могу с уверенностью говорить, что дружелюбности к новичкам (и не только) тут могло быть и больше (хотя, возможно, это действительно самый дружелюбный ресурс в рунете =))

И дело вовсе не в наличии язвительных или немного грубоватых комментариев. Нет, их тоже хватает, но проблема в другом. Она кроется в безразличии, отрешенности и в итоге сухому вердикту - "удалить", "закрыть", "запретить". Конечно, итоговая формулировка немного проливает свет на причину - "Не подходит под формат", "Вопрос слишком общий" и так далее, но новичку от этого проще не станет.

Порой между удалением и созданием вопроса проходит всего какой - то час. А за это время исправить вопрос бывает непросто.

Намного легче и удобнее пройти мимо вопроса и поставить штамп непригоден, чем помочь автору привести мысли в порядок.

Теперь что касается второй части

> И отдельная группа вопросов: что с этим делать? По порядку: плох ли
>   сложившийся порядок (может хорош и менять ничего не надо?), если плох,
>   то нужно ли что-то менять? Если менять, то как (допустим, ставить
>   тревоги на подобные комментарии чтобы потом их вырезали).

Что удивительно система предусматривает решение этой проблемы, хотя решению уделяют мало внимания - чаты. Да, именно чаты решают (или, если говорить более точно, - могут решить) большую часть из имеющихся проблем.

Непонятна суть вопроса? - Создаем отдельный чат, в котором будут помогать автору привести вопрос в порядок.

Вопрос слишком общий? - Отправляем в [общий](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или конкретный чат (например, [F#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f), [C#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--))

Вопрос домашнее задание? - Тоже лучше обратится в конкретную комнату. Часть новичков не показывают свои попыток решения не потому, что их нет, а потому, что стесняются показать.

Так что менять что-то определенно нужно.

Ответ на вопрос как? зависит от гибкости системы, а именно - ограничение на репутацию. Тут есть несколько способов - или убрать ограничение для некоторых отдельных комнат или разрешить RO подключать пользователей к чату с недостаточным количеством баллов. Альтернативный вариант - ставить "+" (временный или постоянный) к вопросу, чтобы у автора появился доступ. Но уверен, что есть и другие варианты.

Было бы желание что-то изменить, а инструмент найдется.

Answer (score 3):

В комментариях под сообщениями иногда встречается сухая аргументированная критика. Без смягчающих выражений, чёткое изложение проблем сообщения. Почему бы нет? ИТ очень техническая прагматическая среда, где правят бал формальные языки и спецификации. Меньше воды, больше дела.

Конечная цель публикации этой критики, как правило, улучшение критикуемого материала. Изложение этой критики требует усилий и, как правило, требует хоть немного вникнуть в вопрос.

**Но временами эта критика воспринимается адресатами совершенно неадекватно.**

---

Некоторые участники *почему-то* воспринимают её как приговор "твой вопрос хлам, уходи", из которого, гипотетически, может последовать минусня, закрывашки и прочие неприятные вещи, возможно даже баны. И дабы не навлекать на себя дальнейший гнев сообщества, бросают всё и убегают.

И делают это, *совершенно забыв*, что свои сообщения можно исправлять, даже закрытые, в результате чего может последовать переоткрытие, плюсики, новые привилегии и прочие пряники.

А чтобы получить бан какого-либо вида в попытках использовать Stack Overflow по назначению, придётся сильно постараться. Нужно удерживаться от прочтения и/или осмысления справки и Меты, даже не пытаться искать решения для собственных проблем (казалось бы, кто если не ТС больше всего заинтересован в решении)... можно ругаться, в конце концов. Вот только при использовании SO по назначению вам и в голову не придёт что-либо из этого делать намеренно!

SO чем-то похож на бытовую технику: ругаться на него бесполезно, надо осмотреть весь корпус, все кнопочки и надписи к ним, ознакомиться с инструкцией. Позже, возможно даже вникнуть в устройство, чтобы пользоваться эффективнее.

---

Редко, но встречаются особые сорта участников, которые воспринимают критику как личные оскорбления, мол, "смотри сколько проблем ты у меня в вопросе нашёл, большой какой, новичков унижаешь, да?"

Какая, собственно, разница, какие мотивы у критика? Если нашлись реальные проблемы — их исправление с большой вероятностью встретит в сообществе поощрение. Если проблемы кажутся надуманными — рассмотреть их всё равно стоит. Если в результате образуется вывод, что проблемы надуманные и исправлять их нет необходимости — что ж, он пытался вам помочь, вы отказались. Возможно не зря отказались, но это маловероятно.

---

Это я всё к чему.

Мы, опытные участники, можем сколько угодно пересматривать собственное отношение к новичкам. Пытаться быть мягче, хоронить реальные проблемы в смягчениях настолько, что они перестают казаться значительными и на них забивают разные объекты, имеющие в составе цилиндрические поверхности.

Но надо понимать, что это проблема с обеих сторон. Опытные участники бывают жестковаты, но неопытные участники не всегда понимают то, что им пытаются сказать.

*Не очень представляю, как можно с этим бороться.*

Comment: Согласен. Не всегда есть силы писать «Здравствуйте. Будьте так добры, добавьте пожалуйста код в ваш ответ в виде текста, а не скриншота.»

Answer (score 3):

Я тут ещё со времён хешкода сижу и заметил такую закономерность - чем больше становится рейтинг человека, тем он становится язвительней. Особенно это заметно, если разница в рейтингах спрашивающего и отвечающего слишком большая.
Как правило это касается новичков, у которых всего десяток/сотня рейтинга. Деды начинают минусовать и язвить в комментариях.

Забавно тут то, что если бы такой вопрос задал человек с рейтингом больше 1000, к примеру, то они вели бы себя по-другому.

> А на деле? Не выглядит ли это со стороны как "я зашёл, создал
>   НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ вопрос, а мне в комментариях начали язвить, плюнул -- ушёл
>   с сайта"?

Да, и не раз. Но, с одной стороны, новички не в курсе правил, они хотят помощи здесь и сейчас, с другой же, деды, которые уже кучу таких вопросов повидали, и им это надоело. 
Но, как по мне, всё равно нужно быть терпимей.

Я бы предложил быть чуточку добрее. К новичкам нужно относиться как к маленьким детям и направлять их на верный путь.

А если говорить про то "be nice", то да, на фоне en SO тут лучше. Если же говорить о ru SO как о самодостаточном портале, то есть куда расти.

Comment: Самый [Chaotic Evil](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) участник, стало быть.

Comment: @alexolut не будите зверя, а то призовёте ненароком =D

Comment: Не согласен наполовину. Не раз ловил себя на мысли "у него 5к репы, неужели он так и не нацчился задавать/оформлять вопросы/ответы?" и "у него 126к репы, по идее ответ правильный, не буду лезть" ))